# Count Cells (within criteria) Offset from other Cells (with criteria)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was requested to create a formula to calculate the number Forecast dates categorized by month across dis-joined ranges.  I also have to calculate the number of milestones completed (within 5 days) based on the Forecast Date (which is 2 rows down from the forecast date row).

I also can't change the data, or add anything to the original sheet.  The Range will add rows as projects are added.

Formula Only - No Macros

```
A            B           C           D
             Milestone    M1          M2          M3
Project X    ORIG. PLAN  5/19/2014  6/23/2014   6/23/2014
             FORE-CAST   7/3/2014   11/21/2014  8/11/2014
             ACTUAL      7/16/2014  12/2/2014   
             MS Delay:   13         11          
             MS Missed:  0          0           0
             MS Score:   100%       100%        20%
Project Y    ORIG. PLAN  5/6/2014   5/6/2014    5/29/2014
             FORE-CAST   5/6/2014   5/6/2014    6/6/2014
             ACTUAL      5/29/2014  5/29/2014   5/29/2014
             MS Delay:   23         23          0
             MS Missed:  0          0           0
             MS Score:   100%       100%        100%
```

I'm having some trouble coming up with the right Formula using the INDEX and MATCH functions to even count the dates with a specified range, let alone the offset.

Ideally the Output would look like this

```
                            May 2014    Jun 2014    July 2014
# of Milestones             2           1           1
# of Milestones Achieved    0           1           0
```

Comment: I think this is totally doable with formulas, but I can't figure out how you got your counts in the output section. Can you elaborate more on the Output?

Comment: The # of Milestones are just a Count of the FORE-CAST dates within the month specified.  The # of Milestones Achieved is the count of MS Delay >=0 and < 5 (but not blank).

Comment: And the # of milestones acheived?

Comment: The same conditions as the # of Milestones, but also look 2 rows down at the MS Delay which should be >=0, <=5 and not blank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some judicious use of `SUMPRODUCT` with staggered ranges should be able to do this without `OFFSET`.

[image: Staggered SUMs]

The formulas are:

```
H1 ► =EDATE(EOMONTH(MIN(INDEX(($C$2:$E$999)+($C$2:$E$999<EDATE(TODAY(), -24))*1E+99, , )), -1)+1, COLUMN(A:A)-1)
H2 ► =SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$999="FORE-CAST")*($C$2:$E$999>=H$1)*($C$2:$E$999<EDATE(H$1,1)))
H3 ► =SUMPRODUCT(($B$5:$B$999="MS Delay:")*($C$5:$E$999>=0)*($C$5:$E$999<5)*($C$3:$E$997>=H$1)*($C$3:$E$997<EDATE(H$1,1))*($C$5:$E$999<>""))
```

Fill right as necessary. I've arbitrarily used a two year window to collect the minimum month available.

Note the two staggered ranges of rows in the H3 formula. C3:E997 has the same number of rows as B5:B999 and C5:E999; just offset two rows up.

Comment: I just started thinking down the `SUMPRODUCT` road.  I love `SUMPRODUCT`.  This work perfectly, and is super simple to use/understand.  Thanks

Comment: The formula for H1 was a nice bonus too.